# Does any literature exist hypothesizing Strange Quarks as a candidate for Dark Matter?

Tags: resource-recommendations, dark-matter, quarks

Putting aside the more common suspects behind dark matter: neutrinos. A friend and I were discussing the possibility of Strange Quarks being an alternate candidate for Dark Matter.

If you're not familiar with Strange Quarks (which become clusters of Strange Matter), [have a look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4RNGRyzt10).

Here are the concepts that we discussed in support of the hypothesis:

- Based on the properties of quarks that form a strange matter clump, it seems plausible that the substance would not interact with electromagnetism, and thus be undetectable (to the extent that Dark Matter is).
- At the origin of the universe, it's plausible that a large amount of this substance (Strange Matter) could have escaped in clumps, perhaps proportionate to the amount of Dark Matter we believe to exist in the universe.
- In terms of evidence, the 1987A supernova in the Large Magellanic Cloud (which was hypothesized to produce a quark star) was not large enough to produce a black hole, and scientists haven't been able to detect a neutron star at the place it should be. If a Strange Quark star formed, and Strange Matter indeed doesn't interact with electromagnetism, us not being able to detect what should be there would seem to support the concept.

Is there any research published that tested a hypothesis of this nature and what were the results? My friend has a degree in physics and couldn't locate any research on this, even though he thinks the idea is plausible enough to warrant research, so I figured I'd ask here to see if anyone is aware of anything published.

Alternatively, is there any published research that would seem to disprove this hypothesis?

Comment: *Dark matter interacts with gravity in an unusual way.* This is not a mainstream view.

Comment: @G.Smith thanks. I'll remove that point. This was my friend's explanation and when I questioned him about it just now he conceded it was probably a misinterpretation on his end regarding to the suspected distribution of dark matter. The way it's portrayed as [a halo around a galaxy](https://scitechdaily.com/images/impression-of-the-expected-dark-matter-distribution-around-the-Milky-Way2.jpg) as opposed the the way regular matter is dispersed in a thin spiral / pancake.

Comment: Worth noting that PBS Spacetime is a pop-science outlet and not really a reliable source of information

Comment: @Charlie it's definitely one of the most trustworthy pop science sources, so it shouldn't be dismissed. In fact, I haven't watched the video but I feel it's more likely that OP misinterpreted something than there being an outright mistake in it.

Comment: @Javier For sure they are one of the better ones, I like watching their videos sometimes. Just pointing it out.

Comment: **Based on the properties of quarks that form a strange matter clump, it seems plausible that the substance would not interact with electromagnetism**. This is not true, because quarks have an electric charge.

Comment: @descheleschilder the whole weirdness of the scenario is that the quark soup created here would not have a charge, if I understand correctly. Look into it more closely

Comment: But the individual quarks **do** have charges.

Comment: @J.Todd Atoms also don't have a charge, yet they interact with light quite readily.

Answer (score 2):

Individual quarks can't exist in an unbound state. Try strangelets instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet . The WP article has a reference to a paper that it says discusses them as a dark matter candidate, Witten, 1984, https://sci-hub.tw/10.1103/physrevd.30.272 , but the paper was written before the evidence for dark matter. Searches have been done for naturally occurring strangelets, and I assume the negative results prevent them from being a major component of dark matter. Strongly interacting dark matter would be easy to detect. That's why we're searching for weakly interacting particles now.

Comment: By "Strange Matter" I was referring to Strangelets. Isn't it plausible that strangelets, due to their properties, would not interact with the electromagnetism? (and thus, be hard to detect)

Comment: @J.Todd If you're referring to them being electrically neutral if they're large enough, the answer is no. Electrically-neutral objects made of charged constituents can and do interact electromagnetically. Atoms are electrically neutral, and yet they can still scatter light of the right wavelength to interact with their constituent electrons (otherwise, atomic spectra wouldn't exist). Neutrons are electrically neutral, and yet they can still scatter light that's high enough in energy to interact with their constituent quarks (otherwise, deep inelastic scattering of neutrons wouldn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with   @user273071, that it is not possible to have matter composed of the quarks belonging to the [mainstream standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). There will always be higher order interactions and decays  which will give rise to visible light and thus cannot be candidates for dark matter. [Strangelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangelet)

> A strangelet is a hypothetical particle consisting of a bound state of roughly equal numbers of up, down, and strange quarks.

Thus it is made up of mainstream standard model quarks.

There exist theories beyond the standard model that allow for fundamentally  very heavy quarks [called WIMPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_interacting_massive_particles) that are only weakly interacting so are candidates [of dark matter.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_matter)

> a WIMP is a new elementary particle which interacts via gravity and any other force (or forces), potentially not part of the Standard Model itself, which is as weak as or weaker than the weak nuclear force, but also non-vanishing in its strength. Many WIMP candidates are expected to have been produced thermally in the early Universe, similarly to the particles of the Standard Model according to Big Bang cosmology, and usually will constitute cold dark matter

Wimps are one of the possible dark matter candidates, and are sought after by high energy particle experiments at [the LHC.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider)

This answer is in place of  a comment